# Concatenate 2 arrays using explode

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

How to output it in view using Codeigniter... in this format

```
brocolli  1/2 kilo

soy sauce 1 bottle
```

Controller:

```
$ingredient_name =implode(",",$_POST["mytext"]); //contains ex. [brocolli,soy sauce]
$ingredient_value = implode(",", $_POST["mytext2"]); //contains ex. [1/2 kilo, 1 bottle]...
```

Comment: Do you have an array or string?

Comment: the $ingredient_name and $ingredient_value will become an array of strings .. i think i will be using explode but i cant make it like a name=>value pair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather use explode on the example you're showing on posted fields values. Then you can use array_combine:

```
$ingredient_name = explode(",",$_POST["mytext"]);
$ingredient_value = explode(",", $_POST["mytext2"]);
$result = array_combine($ingredient_name, $ingredient_value);
```

Now $result is a single array that holds your keys and their respective values.

Comment: how do i extract it in view?

Comment: foreach($result as $key=>$value) {

Answer (score 0):

From the information you have provided, I'm assuming that the first array contains the list of ingredients and the second array contains the ingredient amounts, and you want to put the array into key/value pairs.

This should do the trick:

```
$ingredients = [];
$ingredient_names = explode(",", $_POST['mytext']);
$ingredient_values = explode(",", $_POST['mytext2']);

// combine values into a single array
foreach ($ingredient_names as $i => $name) {
    $ingredients[$name] = $ingredient_values[$i];
}

// output the ingredients however you want
echo "Ingredients:<br>";
foreach ($ingredients as $name => $amount) {
    echo "{$name} {$amount}<br>";
}
```